# How to get Azure user's client secrete (without registering app) or how to generate bearer access token of current Azure credential?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I am trying to create Resource Group and Virtual Machine (and other components) programmatically using C#. I want to use

```
SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecrete, tenantId, environment);
```

But I don't know my client Secrete. How to get it or generate it? Or how to generate the bearer access token of current Azure user credential for restful api call?

The file  %userprofile%.azure\accessTokens.json contains bearer access token. But it is generated by Azure Cli. Is there a way to generate the token via C# code?

This article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal shows a way but it needs to register an app and grant it certain permission (I don't have the permission to grant the permission to app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided is the correct way to use `SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal`, if you just have a user account rather than a valid service principal, the best way in this case is to use [`Azure.Identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity?view=azure-dotnet) to auth, make sure your user account has the permission to create the VM, i.e. [RBAC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal) at the scope you want to create the VM.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources.Models;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Compute.Models;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Network;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Network.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

namespace CreateVMSample
{
    public class Program
    {
        protected static string AdminUsername = "<username>";
        protected static string AdminPassword = "<password>";

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var subscriptionId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID");
            var resourceClient = new ResourcesManagementClient(subscriptionId, new DefaultAzureCredential());

            // Create Resource Group
            Console.WriteLine("--------Start create group--------");
            var resourceGroups = resourceClient.ResourceGroups;
            var location = "westus2";
            var resourceGroupName = "QuickStartRG";
            var resourceGroup = new ResourceGroup(location);
            resourceGroup = await resourceGroups.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, resourceGroup);
            Console.WriteLine("--------Finish create group--------");

            // Create a Virtual Machine
            await Program.CreateVmAsync(subscriptionId, "QuickStartRG", location, "quickstartvm");

            // Delete resource group if necessary
            //Console.WriteLine("--------Start delete group--------");
            //await (await resourceGroups.StartDeleteAsync(resourceGroupName)).WaitForCompletionAsync();
            //Console.WriteLine("--------Finish delete group--------");
            //Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static async Task CreateVmAsync(
            string subscriptionId,
            string resourceGroupName,
            string location,
            string vmName)
        {
            var computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(subscriptionId, new DefaultAzureCredential());
            var networkClient = new NetworkManagementClient(subscriptionId, new DefaultAzureCredential());
            var virtualNetworksClient = networkClient.VirtualNetworks;
            var networkInterfaceClient = networkClient.NetworkInterfaces;
            var publicIpAddressClient = networkClient.PublicIPAddresses;
            var availabilitySetsClient = computeClient.AvailabilitySets;
            var virtualMachinesClient = computeClient.VirtualMachines;

            // Create AvailabilitySet
            Console.WriteLine("--------Start create AvailabilitySet--------");
            var availabilitySet = new AvailabilitySet(location)
            {
                PlatformUpdateDomainCount = 5,
                PlatformFaultDomainCount = 2,
                Sku = new Azure.ResourceManager.Compute.Models.Sku() { Name = "Aligned" }
            };
            availabilitySet = await availabilitySetsClient.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, vmName + "_aSet", availabilitySet);

            // Create IP Address
            Console.WriteLine("--------Start create IP Address--------");
            var ipAddress = new PublicIPAddress()
            {
                PublicIPAddressVersion = Azure.ResourceManager.Network.Models.IPVersion.IPv4,
                PublicIPAllocationMethod = IPAllocationMethod.Dynamic,
                Location = location,
            };

            ipAddress = await publicIpAddressClient.StartCreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, vmName + "_ip", ipAddress)
                .WaitForCompletionAsync();

            // Create VNet
            Console.WriteLine("--------Start create VNet--------");
            var vnet = new VirtualNetwork()
            {
                Location = location,
                AddressSpace = new AddressSpace() { AddressPrefixes = new List<string>() { "10.0.0.0/16" } },
                Subnets = new List<Subnet>()
                {
                    new Subnet()
                    {
                        Name = "mySubnet",
                        AddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/24",
                    }
                },
            };
            vnet = await virtualNetworksClient
                .StartCreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, vmName + "_vent", vnet)
                .WaitForCompletionAsync();

            // Create Network Interface
            Console.WriteLine("--------Start create Network Interface--------");
            var nic = new NetworkInterface()
            {
                Location = location,
                IpConfigurations = new List<NetworkInterfaceIPConfiguration>()
                {
                    new NetworkInterfaceIPConfiguration()
                    {
                        Name = "Primary",
                        Primary = true,
                        Subnet = new Subnet() { Id = vnet.Subnets.First().Id },
                        PrivateIPAllocationMethod = IPAllocationMethod.Dynamic,
                        PublicIPAddress = new PublicIPAddress() { Id = ipAddress.Id }
                    }
                }
            };
            nic = await networkInterfaceClient
                .StartCreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, vmName + "_nic", nic)
                .WaitForCompletionAsync();

            // Create VM
            Console.WriteLine("--------Start create VM--------");
            var vm = new VirtualMachine(location)
            {
                NetworkProfile = new Azure.ResourceManager.Compute.Models.NetworkProfile { NetworkInterfaces = new[] { new NetworkInterfaceReference() { Id = nic.Id } } },
                OsProfile = new OSProfile
                {
                    ComputerName = vmName,
                    AdminUsername = Program.AdminUsername,
                    AdminPassword = Program.AdminPassword,
                    LinuxConfiguration = new LinuxConfiguration { DisablePasswordAuthentication = false, ProvisionVMAgent = true }
                },
                StorageProfile = new StorageProfile()
                {
                    ImageReference = new ImageReference()
                    {
                        Offer = "UbuntuServer",
                        Publisher = "Canonical",
                        Sku = "18.04-LTS",
                        Version = "latest"
                    },
                    DataDisks = new List<DataDisk>()
                },
                HardwareProfile = new HardwareProfile() { VmSize = VirtualMachineSizeTypes.StandardB1Ms },
                AvailabilitySet = new Azure.ResourceManager.Compute.Models.SubResource() { Id = availabilitySet.Id }
            };

            var operation = await virtualMachinesClient.StartCreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, vmName, vm);
            var result = (await operation.WaitForCompletionAsync()).Value;
            Console.WriteLine("VM ID: " + result.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("--------Done create VM--------");
        }
    }
}
```

Source - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-samples-net-management/blob/master/samples/compute/create-virtual-machine/Program.cs

This sample uses [`DefaultAzureCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) of `Azure.Identity` to auth, it will try the following credentials in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) to auth automatically, one of them is [`VisualStudioCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.visualstudiocredential?view=azure-dotnet), means it will use the logged user account of your VS. You can also use it directly, replace all the `DefaultAzureCredential` with `VisualStudioCredential` in the sample code.

Besides, if you still want to get the token to call the REST API manually, you could use the code below.

```
var tokenCredential = new VisualStudioCredential();
var accessToken = await tokenCredential.GetTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com");
```

Comment: I tried `var resourceGroupList = (new ResourcesManagementClient(subscriptionId, new DefaultAzureCredential())).ResourceGroups.List().ToList();`, it worked. Thank you.